# How can i refresh my child componet by using a button click on parent componet?

Tags: reactjs

I am new to this stackoverflow world. Please help me here. How can i refresh the child component based on the button click from the parent component. For example, i have a button in parent component called refresh and not passing any state variables or props to child component. but i want the child component to loaded again based on the button click of parent. I tried adding a state variable, but it was not updating the child component.

parent component:

```
import React from "react";
import ChildComponentForRefreshTesting from "./ChildComponentForRefreshTesting";

class MyComponent extends React.Component {
 constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.state = { isRefreshClicked : false };
}
 submit() {
   this.setState({ isRefreshClicked: true }, () => this.setState({isRefreshClicked: false}));
}
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Parent Component ------<button onClick={this.submit}>Refresh</button></h1>
      <ChildComponentForRefreshTesting />
    </div>
  )
 }
}

  
  export default MyComponent;
```

child component:

```
import React from 'react'

function ChildComponentForRefreshTesting() {
    return (
        <div>
            child component
            <br />
        </div>
    )
}

export default ChildComponentForRefreshTesting;
```

Comment: if there's nothing to re-render, why re-render? If you pass a prop to your child component and something changed.. it will rerender.

Comment: What  exactly do you mean by *"loaded again"*?

Comment: @S In my example, i am not displaying anything in my child component, but in my actual project, child component displays data with current date. so, that on refresh, it fetchs data for the latest current time.

Comment: can you share how you are fetching data in child component?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing state should re-render the current component and all the child components inside it.

I ran your code and there is a mistake with how you defined the setState method. You need to use arrow function, otherwise `this` will be undefined.

So change your submit button like following and it should work.

```
submit = () => {
  this.setState({ isRefreshClicked: true });
};
```

Here's the stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-f5q3n8?file=src/MyComponent.js

Comment: @gauranga If this helped, marking this as expected answer would be helpful. Thanks in advance 

Answer (score 0):

In class components, you can call `this.forceUpdate()` method to force a rerender.

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#forceupdate

Comment: Also, react won't rerender a component if no changes were made on him. In OP case the child component doesn't suffer from any change.